# Abstract algebra introductory book with lots of problems

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am self studying abstract algebra and i am looking for a introductory book with lots of problems ranging from lower level to higher level of difficulty. Also book should be intuitively explain concepts.

Thanks

Comment: I like Gallian's intro algebra book (contemporary abstract algebra iirc)

Comment: Go with Herstein's Topics in Algebra (whose PDF is available). He explains the concepts with a lot of examples and the exercises provide a good workout.